# What is the constant of hyperbolicity?

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds, topological-vector-spaces, diffeomorphism

I am studying dynamical systems of discrete time, and I am having some trouble in understanding what is the constant of hyperbolicity for a closed hyperbolic set $\Lambda \in M$ of a diffeomorphism $f:M\rightarrow M$, where $M$ is a compact differentiable manifold.

Comment: It would be helpful if you state the definition you're using and what parts of it you're having trouble understanding.

Comment: In fact an exact reference would be better, though from the context it seems the constant is an exponential rate with which infinitesimally close orbit converge or diverge from one another.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4126880/169085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the closed subset $\Lambda\subseteq M$ is $f$-invariant and (uniformly) $f$-hyperbolic, so that there is a continuous splitting $T_\Lambda M=S(f)\oplus U(f)$ and for some fixed $C^0$ Riemannian metric on $M$ there two numbers $(\lambda,\rho)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^2$ with $\lambda <1 <\rho$ and another number $C\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that for any $x\in \Lambda$ and for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$:

$$\forall v\in S_x(f)\setminus0: |T_xf^n v|_{f^n(x)}\leq C \lambda^n |v|_x \text{ and }$$

$$\forall v\in U_x(f)\setminus0: |T_xf^{-n} v|_{f^{-n}(x)}\leq C \rho^{-n} |v|_x,$$

then the **constant of hyperbolicity** for $f:\Lambda\to \Lambda$ is either $\lambda$, or $\rho$, or some other number $\kappa\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $\lambda\leq\kappa<1<\kappa^{-1}\leq\rho$ (e.g. if you are following Shub's *Global Stability of Dynamical Systems* (p.82) (or Pilyugin's *The Space of Dynamical Systems with the $C^0$-Topology* (p.62)).

In ODE theory this situation is sometimes referred to as an **exponential $(\lambda,\rho)$-dichotomy**. The actual numbers become important when it comes to subtle estimates (or more sophisticated versions of hyperbolicity), but roughly the idea is that that there are such constants guarantees a good separation of vectors that correspond to infinitesimally different behaviors; any vector approximates arbitrarily well either a vector in the stable subbundle or the unstable subbundle if enough time passes. This provides a robust theory (e.g. in the definition above one doesn't need to assume that the splitting is continuous; in fact not only is it continuous but Hölder continuous). I personally find the "Mather diagram" very useful to keep track of such numbers, such a diagram looks like this:

[image]

(What this is is really the spectrum, up to rotation, of the adjoint operator of $f$ acting on the space of continuous vector fields; $X\mapsto Tf\circ X\circ f^{-1}$.)

As a suggestive example, one can consider an invertible $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ with both eigenvalues real and modulus different than $1$. (Also see [Space of linear, continuous, hyperbolic functions is open, dense in the set of invertible functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2798482/169085) for a related discussion.)